# Make element selected/active (like when you using tab)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make element lets say button active on page open. By active I mean when u pressing tab buttons elements, tabs and stuff us getting active one after one. But how can I achieve that element is selected defaulty on page start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

`element.focus();`

[Link to javascript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus)

Comment: Yeah thank you, thats what I was looking for. The only problem is it wont work for me. Probably is fighting with some other focus()

Answer (score 1):

All HTML elements have a [Boolean attribute `autofocus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autofocus). It does not only work on form elements such as buttons, input fields, dropdowns, but also on focussable elements like `<div contenteditable="true">`.